# Simulate Atom based pc environment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cpu

I need to run & test an application on Atom cpu based tablet PC. I tried remote debugging ability of VS2010 but it only handles exceptions.

My multi-threaded application's behaviors are totally different on that tablet PC. Is there any way to simulate Atom cpu -low speed, single core, etc- on my desktop environment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use power saving settings to limit the CPU speed, and CPU affinity to prevent your process from using all cores.  I don't know of an easy way to artificially limit use of CPU caches.

Configuring power saving settings would be more appropriate for SuperUser.

For affinity, you can p/invoke [`SetProcessAffinityMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

However, the Atom has a very different internal architecture, so merely dialing down clock speed will not be a very accurate simulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit number of CPUs available by changing boot.ini http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170756 or Win 7 - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-System-Configuration (start -> system configuration -> boot ->advanced).